# How to return json by default for visual studio web api

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I just created a Web API project in Visual Studio 2013, and when I go to a sample restful URL in my browser, like `http://localhost/values/5`, it returns XML. How do I make it so that it returns JSON by default instead of XML? Something in my `Global.asax` file? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Web API returns the service document in AtomPub format. To request JSON you can add the following header to the HTTP request:

```
Accept: application/json
```

or you can remove xml media type support at all in Global.asax

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, I had to put this code not in Global.asax, but instead in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs